# Importing JTransforms library

Tags: java, android, fft, libraries

I downloaded and compiled JTransforms-3.0 into my project and I can see it in the hierarchy here:

[image]

I'm running into issues on when I try to import it.

```
import edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D;
```

It says it cannot resolve the symbol "edu" and I can get an error saying that the package doesn't exist. I'm using android studio and I have the libraries in my gradle file under the dependencies. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Its says the file is `org.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D`...

Comment: How did you import the library? just coping it in lib folder? You should add it via java Build Path

Comment: In an interesting turn of events, it isn't importing correctly now. I have a message saying "cannot resolve symbol 'DoubleFFT_1D.'" Any additional thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solve the problem still but I had to go through the same path as well. I ended up going to the Jtransform's GitHub page and downloading the "JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar" file. Placing it in the "libs" folder, right click "Add as a library" and works perfectly! :)

[JTransform's github page](http://JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar)

Answer (score 0):

It should be imported like this:

```
dependencies {
    ... 
    implementation 'com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:3.1'
}
```